# How to play YouTube video automatically only in active slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I added slider using bootstrap 4 and now i want to auto-play YouTube video only on active slider . if slider changes video will pause. can anyone suggest me how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use autoplay property on video element [here you can read more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/autoplay)

```
for js: document.querySelector('#video').autoplay = true;
    or: document.getElementById("video_player").setAttribute('autoplay', true);
for jquery: $("#video_player")[0].autoplay = true;
    or: $("#video_player")[0].play();
```

Comment: i am using iframe tag

Comment: <div class="carousel-item">                
                <div class="video-container-desktop">
                  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pgarH0a0Oj4?controls=0&rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: problem is that , if i use autoplay property in url then all slide will play automatically. i just want to play active slide

Comment: If you don't force the play() through javascript, attributes might not work, depending on the settings in the browser, since autoplay features could be disabled

Comment: try to add autoplay only for active slides like document.querySelector('.active iframe').src += '?autoplay=1'